# How can I use Hadoop/Map-Reduce/etc?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a program that I wish to compute by splitting it up across many computers. Is this something I can accomplish with Hadoop or Map/Reduce, and if so, how do I begin using it? Does it cost money to use that many computers?

Answer (score 0):

You can split you program depending on the nature of your algorithm. You should split the input data and on each node apply your program on a subset of that input. That is, you should implement a data parallelism. In each node execute the same program but on a smaller input.

My advice, take a look to the book "Hadoop, the definitive guide", the first two chapters can help you to understand something better.
If you want to try simple MapReduce programs as WordCount you can download the Hortonworks sandbox which you can install on a virtual machine and you'll have a single node hadoop installation very quickly. Here is the link http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/

Comment: I'm asking how I even use it. Do I need access to a computer farm to use hadoop?